# Android Development: 2d Best way to do RPG?

Tags: android, 2d, tiles, map-edit

Im developing a 2d RPG using surfaceview.
This is how Ive done:

- I have a Tile bitmap that is basicly the whole world that i did in Photoshop.
- I have 1 Array which contains number 0 and 1. 1 means collision and 0 mean Ok to walk.

But this is very slow because if i want to change something i ahve to go to photoshop change the world.png then go into the array with 100 items and change collsion right.

Isnt there a faster way to do this? Ive tried MapEditor but it exports as .TMX and I have no idea how to read that.

Any help how to make this better, any link any idea whould be really appritiaded!

//Simon

Comment: probably belongs on the game developers stackexchange site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use lots of little tiles that would make up your world, each tile would have a definition that would make it passable or impassable, the level of the (z-height) of the tile and any other information you could want.

Why not create your own file format and load that?

Comment: hmm i made a mapeditor in .NET a while ago.
Btw, is there anyway to select a part of a bitmap in eclipse. Because i have a bitmap with grass,asphalt and so on?

Comment: Unknown. I haven't used Eclipse in a long while, but I would guess there would be a bitmap editor for it.